# SwiftUI - Sheet Dismmis button not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to add a button on the top of my view that will be the "X" to close the sheet. I am unable to use `presentationmode` option. For some reason it isn't working. Can someone please let me know how I can add a button that shows an "X" on the top that if I click on will close this view. Your help is very much appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TopicsExperienceCards: View {
   // @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    let etype: EItype
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            /* Alernatively Page Layout View */
        ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(etype.accentcolor))
                .frame(width: 300, height: 5)
                .padding()
            GroupBox {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(etype.content1,id: \.self) {item in
                       VStack (alignment:.center, spacing:0){
                                Text(item)
                                    .padding()
                                    .frame(width:300, height:300, alignment:.center)
                        Divider()

                Spacer()
                Text("Room for an image")
                        Spacer()
                        Spacer()
                        }
                } //foreach
                } //: TABVIEW
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
               .onAppear {
                setupAppearance() }
                } //end of GroupBox
           // .padding()
            .frame(width:350, height:650)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0, style: .circular))
            .shadow(radius: 5)
            } //end of ScrollView
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    } //end of Navigation view
        }
    }

/* Function for the black dots in pagination */
func setupAppearance() {
    UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black
    UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
  }

struct TopicsExperienceCards_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let etypes: [EItype] = Bundle.main.decode("eibasestructure.json")
    static var previews: some View {
        TopicsExperienceCards(etype:etypes[1])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in the `Binding` that you use to present the sheet to `TopicsExperienceCards` as well.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present") {
            isPresented = true /// set Binding to true to present
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            TopicsExperienceCards(isPresented: $isPresented) /// pass Binding here
        }
    }
}

struct TopicsExperienceCards: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    isPresented = false /// set Binding back to false
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .padding()
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]